# How to write two where conditions in DB query in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-migrations

I have one query which will check one column values by using where condition now I want to check one more column in the query by using where condition please help me

```
DB::table('contents')->where('name','Python')->get();
```

Now that I need is to check one more condition `where('price',null)` is there any way inorder to write two where conditions with one where condition it will check both conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can just chain multiple where conditions, so :

```
DB::table('contents')->where('name','Python')->where('price',null)->get();
```

would work fine.

Comment: My doubt is ,is there anyway to write single where condition which will check both conditions

Comment: No. You could have a single "where" to check multiple values of, say, "name". But to the best of my knowledge you cannot use one "where" to check the values of multiple different fields. You would not in a direct SQL query...

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make an array of conditions. So the query will be,

```
DB::table('contents')->where([['name','Python'], ['price', null]])->get();
```

Let me know its solves your issue or not.

Comment: In my question query I store that entire query in variable , based on that variable I am calling name as $temp[0]->name, now it's showing error

Comment: Can you please share how you stored the query in a variable? also share `temp` array.

Comment: also share errors, please. @Sravani